# performance of an object with an array vs an array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, big-o

I've been doing a lot of algorithms in JS, and in some of them it's more efficient to create an object (dictionary) for faster (constant lookup O(1) or O(N)) rather than an array.

eg.

```
const items1 = {
    'a': 2,
    'b': 2
}
```

is more efficient than having

```
const items1 = [
    ['a', 2],
    ['b', 2]
]
```

for data lookups in terms of time and (space?) complexity?

but what if I had an array as the value within the object? is it still faster than having just an array?

```
const items1 = {
    1: [['a', 2]],
    2: [['b', 2]]
}
```

Comment: Your mixing complexity up with efficiency. There is no way that your first example is measurably more **efficient** than your second.

Comment: "Faster" *for what*? If you can write `items1[foo]`, that is virtually instantaneous. If you need to write `items1.find(i => i[0] == foo)`, that's infinitely slower.

Comment: It'll basically always be more efficient to have key-value pairs in an object, rather than storing them as 2-element arrays. Looking up a value by its key is (part of) the purpose of using objects in JS, so engines will always optimise this common use. They probably won't optimise iterating through an array and matching the first element in order to look up the second in the same way.

Comment: so the best would be something like const items1 = {'1': 'a2', '2':'b2'}?

Comment: There is no "best"

Answer (score 2):

> and in some of them it's more efficient to create an object (dictionary) for faster (constant lookup O(1) or O(N)) rather than an array

JavaScript objects aren't just simple dictionaries. But yes, looking up a property by name on an object is **much** faster than searching for a match in an array. (Whereas looking up a specific entry in an array, say `a[0]`, is just as fast if not faster than looking up a property in an object, because arrays *are* objects [more [on my blog]](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), but can be further optimized into being true arrays.)

> but what if I had an array as the value within the object? is it still faster than having just an array?

It can't be. If you do that, then you have to:

1. Look up the property on the object to get the array
2. Look up what you want in the array

Whereas if you were using just an array, you wouldn't need Step 1.

---

Side note: You have too many `[` and `]`s, unless you relaly wanted an object with properties whose values were arrays *containing* arrays. So:

```
const items1 = {
    1: ['a', 2],
    2: ['b', 2]
}
```

Comment: so the best would be something like const items1 = {'1': 'a2', '2':'b2'}?

Comment: @totalnoob - I can't make out what you're trying to compare.